# Moving text file to integer list

Tags: python

Trying to read a file with vertically written numbers.Why does the code below skip the 1st, 3rd, 5th... etc lines of the opened file?

```
f.open(r'...txt','r')
A=[]
for line in f:
    x=f.readline()
    A.append(int(x))
print(A)
...
f.close()
```

Comment: `for line in f` is giving you each line of the file. You are ignoring `line` and reading *another* line into `x`.

Comment: `for line in f` will read each line in the file and each line will be in variable `line` inside the for loop. So just `A.append(int(line))` is all that's needed. `f.readline()` also reads each line of the file each time you call it incrementing to the next line. It's like you are reading one line via your `for` loop, then capturing the next with `readline()`. So every other line...

Comment: `for line in f` -> one line (unused), `x=f.readline()` -> next line (used)